# Javascript: Close Popup, Open New Window & Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, onclick

I would like to close the current popup, open a new window (tab) and redirect to a specific link. This works extremly easy with my `<a>` links. I simply add **"target="_blank""** and it works just fine (it doesnt close the pop up actually, but minimizes it and thats fine too).

Since I am using some buttons with a onclick function, I want to implent the "target="_blank" in the button somehow... The button looks like this at the moment:

```
<input type="button" onclick="parent.window.opener.location='http://google.com'; window.close();">
```

This works, but the problem is that it redirects in the parent window and doesnt open a new window...

Any1 has an idea how to get the feature of "target="_blank" so that a click on button will open a new window and than redirect instead of redirecting the parent window?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not just use this in your onclick:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); window.close();" />
```

Comment: This seems to works great!! Thanks a lot! I was just confused by all the different possibilities and didnt think of the easy way!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#button').click(function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 window.open('http://www.facebook.com/','_blank');
});

<input type="button" id="button" value="Go facebook">
```

It works un IExplorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari

Answer (score 2):

jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function() {
        window.close();
        window.open('http://www.google.com/'); 
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="click me">
```

It works OK in Chrome and IE. In Firefox, you must open this code with `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='http://google.com' onclick='window.close();' target='_blank'>LINK</a>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick reply, but please read my question before answering! target='_blank' works fine, but I cant use <input type='button' target='_blank' .......

Comment: no you cannot. you can use window.open() on the onclick on the button