# How to close popup and redirect a page

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup

My site using php and i create an online quiz and the quiz show in pop up mode.
Currently when i want to redirect my page using the script below. it goes to my homepage BUT it still at the pop up mode. I want it to close the pop up and go to homepage after I click finish.

How can I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.parent.location = "../../../"

</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the window that opened a popup with the `window.opener` property on the popup. So, something like this should work:

```
window.opener.location.replace(redirectUrl);
window.close;
```

If you wanted to put that behavior in the `onclick` event on a submit button you're building like this:

```
echo "<input type=\"submit\" 
       name=\"finishattempt\" 
       value=\"".get_string("finishattempt", "quiz")."\" 
       onclick=\"$onclick\" />\n";
```

You'd need to assign the String `window.opener.location.href='someUrl';window.close();` to the variable `$onclick` before echoing the submit button out.

Comment: You should put it wherever you want to :) If you want that behavior fired when a certain button is clicked, as [JMax said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552726/how-to-close-popup-and-redirect-a-page/7552782#7552782), you can put it into the `onclick` event handler on that button. Can you explain when do you want to close the popup and redirect the opening page?

Comment: i want it after i click submit button . then the popup will close and go to homepage

Comment: Then, do it as JMax proposed in his answer :)

Comment: how about if my button look like this

 echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"finishattempt\" value=\"".get_string("finishattempt", "quiz")."\" onclick=\"$onclick\" />\n";

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code (used on an HTML button):

```
<input type="button" onclick="parent.window.opener.location='http://homepage.com'; window.close();">
```

And have a look at some similar threads like this one: [Javascript: Close Popup, Open New Window & Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274109/javascript-close-popup-open-new-window-redirect)

[EDIT] See [this article](http://www.linein.org/blog/2009/03/02/javascript-close-popup-and-refresh-or-redirect-parent-window-with-onload-solution/) too

Comment: echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"finishattempt\" value=\"".get_string("finishattempt", "quiz")."\" onclick=\"$onclick\" />\n";

Answer (score 2):

this way you can do it ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function close_window(){
    window.opener.location = 'pop_up.php';
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

html code..

```
<body>
<form method="post" name="frm_2" id="frm_2">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_close" id="btn_close" onclick="return close_window();" />
</form>
</body>
```