# If user gets logged in succesfully, the pop up window closes and then 'mother' website goes to link

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, popup

I use bravenet password protect to protect my pages, and I want, if the user logs in successfully, the pop up to close and the page the pop up came from to go to , for example, google.com ...

So I am giving you the html code of the loin form, the only thing i can do to help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: left;padding-left:5px;"class="login">
<form action="http://pub49.bravenet.com/passwd/show.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="usernum" value="4136972029" />
<div style="padding:3px; font: bold 24px arial;color:#00cccc;">Login</div>
<input style="color:#000000;" type="text" required title="Username required" placeholder="Username" data-icon="U"type="text" name="uname" size="15" maxlength="30" style="width: 100px">
<input style="color:#000000;" type="password" required title="Password required" placeholder="Password" data-icon="x"type="password" name="passwd" size="15" maxlength="30" style="text-aign:center;">
<div> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" style="width: 235px;"> </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Example](http://aunabzzzolutionl.weebly.com/)

The page loads inside the popup, and this sucks :/

Comment: Your button posts the page back, so you can handle the redirection on the server.

Comment: @Tasos If you redirect with JavaScript, is there any point in logging in? What stops me from manually redirecting?

Comment: I'm not getting any popups =/

Comment: The website with the pop up is here: aunabzzzolution.weebly.com , top left corner, press login . ok we login with username: member and password: charlie1 , then the !popup! loads the page, so i want the pop up to close if the login form is submited and the mother website to load the website link that loads on the pop up.. Please help me, of I wont fix the problem , the pop up i made will be deleted cause there will be this problem:/

Comment: @jbabey please explain your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the solution, as JMax Said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552726/how-to-close-popup-and-redirect-a-page/7552782#7552782) i just putted the code in the submit button,and it totaly works :D check yourself: http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/